# PXE install a squashfs root

Tags: boot, pxe

I have a customized bootable ISO image. The iso image has following:

```
/casper
   root.squashfs
   initrd.gz
   vmlinuz
/isolinux
   boot.cat
   isolinux.bin
   isolinux.cfg
   menu.c32
   menu.cfg
```

I try to PXE install this image on multiple hosts.  In my tryout, pxelinux.cfg/default has following content:

```
DEFAULT menu.c32
label  ubuntu14-install
menu label ubuntu14-install
kernel boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.4.100:/ubuntu14 initrd=initrd.gz root=/dev/nfs
```

dhcp server/tftpd/nfs server running on 192.168.4.100, and exported directory /ubuntu14 contains casper directory, which has root.squashfs, kernel and initrd files in it.

However, the client got kernel panic state after configuring the network:

```
...
* Starting configure network device security
* stopping cold plug devices
* stopping log initial device creation
[ 241.356693] INFO: task loop0:515 blocked for more than 120 seconds
[ 241.357549]       Not tainted 3.13.0-62-generic #102-Ubuntu
[ 241.358328] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message
...
```

Is this because initrd.gz is not purposely built for netbooting?

I also tried PXE install standard Ubuntu14.10 distribution, using preseed and ks configuration, and see no issue. But cannot get my customized root.squashfs to be installed by using append option:

```
live-installer/net-image=http://192.168.4.100/Ubuntu14/root.squashfs
```

in pxelinux.cfg/default file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.